# How to create a vector of the results in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I have a problem with the following code. I want to store all the values I am creating in the for loop below so that I can make a plot of it. I have tried several things, but nothing works. Does anyone know a simple method to create a vector of the results and then plot them?

```
dx=0.1;
t=1;
e=1;

for x=-1:dx:1
lower_bound=-100;
upper_bound=x/(sqrt(4*t*e));
    e=1;
u=(1/sqrt(pi))*quad(@integ,lower_bound,upper_bound);
plot(x,u)
hold on
end

hold off
```

I would like to use as much of this matlab code as possible.

Comment: Read MATLAB's documentation on [Loop Control Statements](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html), it has many examples that answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dx=0.1;
t=1;
e=1;
xval=[-1:dx:1].';
upper_bound = zeros(numel(xval),1);
u = zeros(numel(xval),1);
for ii=1:numel(xval)
x = xval(ii)
lower_bound=-100;
upper_bound(ii,1)=x/(sqrt(4*t*e));
u(ii,1)=(1/sqrt(pi))*quad(@integ,lower_bound,upper_bound(ii));
end
figure;
plot(xval,u)
```

by adding the `(ii)` behind your statements it saves your variables in an array. I did not use that on your `lower_bound` since it is a constant.

Note that I first created an array `xval` and called that with integers in `ii`, since subscriptindices must be positive integers in MATLAB. I also initialised both `upper_bound` and `u` by creating a zero matrix before the loop executes. This is handy since extending an existing vector is very memory and time consuming in MATLAB and since you know how big they will get (same number of elements as `xval`) you might as well use that.

I also got the `plot` call outside the loop, to prevent you from plotting 21 blue lines in 1 plot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I do get a problem when writing your code. My error code says that "The limits of integration must be scalars". I use the function function y=integ(x)
y=exp(-x.^2); Do you know what I should change?

Comment: Okay, that worked better. Now I get the correct u-values. The only problem now is that the plot don't show any graph. Should I change the x-values or something?